# How to parse_ini_file from web page

Tags: php, file, html-table, ini

I am trying to parse an ini file hosted on another web server with little to no luck.
I can parse it if I have a test ini file locally, but no such luck if I try to contact a remote server.

Here is the code I have been working with all night.

```
<?php
  $datas  = parse_ini_file( http://example.com/test.ini, true );
?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <?php
      foreach( $datas as $data ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data["name"] ); ?></td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Points</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data["Name"] ); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data["Points"] ); ?></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

`parse_ini_string(file_get_contents('http://example.com/test.ini'), true);`

I'm fairly confident that `parse_ini_file` doesn't support the `http` stream wrapper.

Comment: I am trying to get a file from a public share on Google Drive.  This is what I get.  
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''https://doc-0s-c8-docs.google' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ')' in /home/example/public_html/test/points.html on line 2

Any ideas?

Comment: You're right, that did work!!  I tried dropbox in the public folder, and it worked without a hinge!  You're wonderful! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

`parse_ini_file` expects a filename - i.e. a path to a local file, not a URI (a remote file locator).
See more [in the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)). You need to first download the file, save it locally, and then open it.